# apache switch from prefork to worker and check modules installed

Tags: apache-httpd

I have debian machine and currently apache prefork. I would like to switch to worker mode. I found in phpinfo that these modules are installed:

```
core 
mod_so 
mod_watchdog 
http_core 
mod_log_config 
mod_logio 
mod_version 
mod_unixd 
mod_access_compat 
mod_alias 
mod_auth_basic 
mod_authn_core 
mod_authn_file 
mod_authz_core 
mod_authz_host 
mod_authz_user 
mod_autoindex 
mod_deflate 
mod_dir 
mod_env 
mod_filter 
mod_mime 
prefork 
mod_negotiation 
mod_php7 
mod_reqtimeout 
mod_rewrite 
mod_setenvif 
mod_socache_shmcb 
mod_ssl 
mod_status
```

How can I find out, if all modules will work correctly with worker mode please?

Comment: Don't use `mod_php` with MPM worker or event, it's not thread-safe. 
Switch to `mod_proxy_fcgi` and `php-fpm`, read [Running PHP on Apache httpd](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP).

Comment: hi, am I able to find out, which modules are thread-safe?

Comment: I believe the modules that come with Apache are considered all safe, go throught the list and check the [Module Index](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/). yourself.
Read [Apache HTTP Server 2.x Thread Safety Issues](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/thread_safety.html) and disable all modules you don't actually use.